# How to align 2 rows horizontally in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, alignment

I am making a react app and I have few columns which are to be mapped to values,I want to map the field names horizontally with field values.I tried with the below code but still it is a bit un-aligned.

my code:

Task class:

```
  return (
    
    
    
  
    <div >
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">{task.clientName} </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">{task.clientId}</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">{task.clientSecret}</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">{task.status}</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">{task.generated_on}</a>
      </div>
      {/* <div>
        <FaTimes
          className="clientparams"
          style={{ color: "red", cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() => onDelete(task.clientId)}
        />
      </div> */}
    </div>
    
   
  );
};

    export default Task;
```

Tasks class:

It contains headings.

```
return (
    <div>
     <div className="form1">
    <div>
    <a className="clientparams1">clientName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">clientId</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">clientSecret</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">status</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a className="clientparams1">generated_on</a>
      </div>
      

    </div>
     
      {tasks.map((task, index) => (
        <Task key={index} task={task} onDelete={onDelete} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In this code I have a parent div inside which there are 2 div tags and 1st div has all the field names and 2nd field has all the values to their corresponding field names.

Here are my `css` classes that i am using above:

```
    .clientparams{
   margin: 40px;
   height: 30px;
   width: 250px;
   font-size: medium;
 }

 .form1{
  display: flex;
 
 }

.main_container{
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: justify;
  
  }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your Task component, inside of .form1 div, I have made two div. In the first one, I have added ur client info. and in the second div, I have added the Task component. These 2 divs have their own className client_container and task_container respectively. Their className is assigned with CSS property.

```
return (
    <div className="main_container>
     <div className="form1">
       <div className="client_container">
         <div>
         <a className="clientparams1">clientName</a>
         </div>
         <div>
         <a className="clientparams1">clientId</a>
         </div>
         <div>
         <a className="clientparams1">clientSecret</a>
         </div>
         <div>
         <a className="clientparams1">status</a>
         </div>
         <div>
         <a className="clientparams1">generated_on</a>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div className="task_container">
         {tasks.map((task, index) => (
           <Task key={index} task={task} onDelete={onDelete} />
         ))}
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#css

```
.form1{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.client_container{
display: flex;
}

.task_container{
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: if u want to display add_form horizontally then u have to add display flex property to their parent. In your case first div.

Comment: still not wokring,i think there's an issue with clientparams css class

Comment: hey add display flex to ur main container i.e ur top container. And remove display, justify-content and align items from ur add_form div. It should work fine now

Comment: can u edit ur question code and post ur present code. with css. If u want help

Comment: any changes in the Task component?

Comment: u can remove form1 classname from task component if something doesn't work. and don't use too many divs

Comment: its aligning vertically not horizontally

Comment: updated the main_container css class in the question,can you check it once

Comment: now its aligning everything in just 1 column

Comment: horizontally or vertically. u can choose flex-direction column or row according to ur need.

Comment: I have added the error image after adding flex-direction row

Comment: no,I want a table like structure with filed names in 1st row and corresponding values in the subsquent rows

Comment: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-space-between-rows-in-the-table.html 
like this table

Comment: ok i'll refine my code in 5minutes. sorry i misunderstood

Comment: still a minor alignment error,the field values are still in columns,
heres the error image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPH_Lee2PoAWqsZP3k_c2TgSLCGickcy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that is because of ur task's component CSS and div usages.  Try editing them

Comment: yeah there's no classname in Task class,just a div container wrapping the child.I have updated it in the question

Comment: there is form1 class in the form component. Maybe its because of that. Try editing the form component. It's not complex from there

Comment: still not wokring,can you update the code?

Comment: have u solved it? otherwise i will do it for u

Answer (score 1):

You can try html table like this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>clientName</th>
    <th>clientId</th>
    <th>clientSecret</th>
    <th>status</th>
    <th>generated_on</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{task.clientName}</td>
    <td>{task.clientId}</td>
    <td>{task.clientSecret}</td>
    <td>{task.status}</td>
    <td>{task.generated_on}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope that will solve your issue.